# Replace objects in a collection with one mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

How is it possible to replace objects in a collection with an object while keeping the correct rotation from the collection with geometry node?

[image: starting idea]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...replace objects in a collection with an object while keeping the correct rotation from the collection...?

If we can somehow have direct access to the attributes of the instances, copy the attributes (rotation) of the objects in the collection and then have them transferred to the desired object (Suzanne) then this task should be easy enough to deal with.

[image]

However, since most of things mentioned above aren't available at the moment, in your case, I'd suggest another alternative route by calculating the **angle of rotation between the Z-Vector and the normals of the cubes' faces**. Once you're done with the calculation, you'll get back in return the needed **Euler rotation**, which you'll then use to rotate whatever object you want to replace the cubes with (in this case, Suzanne).

Here's the full set-up.[image]

[image]